# How to delete firebase cache on firebase-admin (nodejs)?

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-admin

I am making a game, where I need POI on a map. For each game I create 10000 POI. Every time I am creating a game, my node server create 10000 POI and posts them to firebase database. (10000 is just a big number to show the problem I have)

My problem is that firebase 'js' is caching all these objects and I have a memory leak.

How can I force firebase to destroy its caches? I don't need these data on the nodejs side, but only on the client sides?

This is the function I am using to create it. I have tried to simplified it.

```
export async function addRandomPois(gameId) {
    const numberOfPoiToBeGeneratedPerKM: number = 10000;
    const sizeInKm = 2;
    const numberOfPoiToBeGenerated = numberOfPoiToBeGeneratedPerKM * sizeInKm;

    const gameData = await GameFirebaseRef.get()
    const game = gameData.data();
    const batches = {0: FirebaseStore.batch()};
    let batchNum = 0;

    for (var n = 0; n < numberOfPoiToBeGenerated; n++) {
        if (n > 0 && n % 500 === 0) {
            // batches cannot have more than 500 operation. So I create as much as needed
            batches[batchNum]
                .commit()
                .then(i => delete batches[batchNum]);
            batchNum++;
            batches[batchNum] = FirebaseStore.batch();
        }
        const generatedRandomPoint = pointInCircle(game.currentCircle.center, game.nextCircle.size);
        const generatedPOI = {
            icon: randomIcon(),
            position: generatedRandomPoint
        }
        const ref = firebasePOIREF.doc(guid());
        batches[batchNum].set(ref, generatedPOI)
    }
    return batches[batchNum].commit()
        .then(i => console.log(`${gameId} : randomly poi generation terminated`))
}
```

Comment: The Firebase admin SDK doesn't maintain any disk caches.  It only holds query results in memory for as long as a listener is active on a query.  If your data set is too big for memory, then you need to do something in your code to reduce the amount of data being returned from a query.  On the client, you don't have any control over the disk cache.  The disk cache should not cause any problems with memory.

Comment: It does keep stuff in cache as it implies in the interface GetOptions
https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/blob/master/packages/firestore-types/index.d.ts

Comment: You've linked to the client SDK, not the Admin SDK.  The Admin SDK has no such options selection.  Also, you've linked to Firestore code, not Realtime Database code. They are different products with different behavior.